# Projection on compact submanifolds

Tags: convex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-manifolds

I know from Hilbert projection theorem that for any non-empty, convex and closed set $C$ of a Hilbert space $X$ that there exists a projection map that maps every element in $X$ to a unique element in $C$.

My question is that, is there any extensions of this theorem (in any direction) that concerns compact submanifolds? For example, the unit circle is a compact manifold which is not convex. I am wondering if there is a projection tool on this type of manifolds.

Comment: You want results about "projections" of points of a manifold $M$ to a submanifold $N\subseteq M$?

Comment: Yes, I am wondering about the existence of such maps and what conditions on the submanifold $N$

Comment: Consider for example the case of a curve on the plane. Most points of the plain are in exactly one line which is normal to the curve — only those on the evolute (the locus of the centers of curvature of the curve) are problematic for this. So projecting along normal lines is workable in this situation. The same thing happens for hypesurfaces of euclidean space. This generalizes to higher codimension and to other ambient manifolds.

Comment: That gives a well studied and very classical interpretation of what you want. There are surely others.

Comment: Any reference to a useful material?

Comment: The case of curves (and a bit of surfaces) is usually treated in textbooks on differential geometry of curves and surfaces.

Comment: This case is very limited. My question looks for the "properties" of sets that are images of projections...For instance, convex closed sets have continuous projection maps on Hilbert spaces....

Comment: I did not say it was not limited. It is what you get if you insist on that the projection be along lines orthogonal to the submanifold. I honestly am not at all familiar with the literature, and you can look for it. Surely more and more general cases have been studied, as this is an obviously interesting problem.

Comment: If you consider a round circle, it is obvious that getting a continuous projection is not going to work, for where are you going to send the center? The points where that happens are focal points of the surface and have been studied for ages —focal curves and surfaces, caustics, etc. Iirc, Arnold's book on mathematical methods in classical physics has a nice treatment of this.

Comment: The general case (whatever one means by general!) is possibly way too difficult. You'll find tons of things about evolutes and focal surfaces in hyperbolic space for example: that difficult and interesting variation comes by simlly changing euclidean space by the next simplest thing...